# Random number generator

Tags: javascript

Util functions to generate random numbers with upper bound or with both upper and lower bounds:

```
var waver = (function() {
    return { between: function(min, max) {
                 return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) + min );
           }
           , until: function(max) {
                 return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max + 1 ) );
           }
};})();
```

Comment: Please more context for why you need bound random numbers.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. Review done.  That being said: I do not understand why the object is called "waver"? Something with the words "random", "select" or "pick" would make more sense. I would also use "upto" instead of "until". The latter most often refers to a point in time, or when something happens, not a specific number.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Could you change the comment? I think that the code is off by one (see my answer. Please notify me because I've linked to the current comment in my answer (due to the naming, that's a fair assessment).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I can't tell whether user275698 intends the result to include or exclude the max value. Returning a exclusive results would be logical: `waver.until(10)` would then return 10 possible values, instead of 11, but as I said, user275698 might have intended to return 11 possible values.

Comment: "Until" is indeed not the word that I would have used in that case - but yeah, handling time is always fickle. Maybe should not put too much fate in that word.

Answer (score 2):

As already indicated [in the comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286567/random-number-generator#comment570450_286567), the naming of the functions is weird. Both `waver` and `until` are not well chosen.

The functions you've provided look very much as the example in the JavaScript documentation for the function [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); // The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

**However**, you can see that the `+ 1` you did isn't there, that's if the `max` value is **inclusive**. However, you've specified "until" as indicator, which would mean that *the intent is to be **exclusive***.

---

The problem with using floating point values and operations is that they are always limited by a specific amount of precision. That in turn will mean that the function is ever so slightly biased. *Usually* this amount of bias can be safely ignored, but now always.

Instead it may be a better idea to use and rejection sampling using integers. Additionally I'd rather use a cryptographically secure random number generator that provides many security properties over `Random`.

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  if (max <= 0 || !Number.isInteger(max)) {
    throw new Error("The max value should be a positive integer.");
  }
  
  const bitLength = Math.ceil(Math.log2(max));
  const byteLength = Math.ceil(bitLength / 8);
  const rejectionLimit = Math.pow(2, bitLength) - max;
  
  const buffer = new Uint8Array(byteLength);
  
  while (true) {
    crypto.getRandomValues(buffer);
    
    let randomValue = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < byteLength; ++i) {
      randomValue |= (buffer[i] << (8 * i));
    }
    
    // Zero out the bits that are out of range, based on bitLength
    randomValue &= (Math.pow(2, bitLength) - 1);
    
    // Reject the sample if it's larger than the max value.
    if (randomValue >= rejectionLimit) {
      continue;
    }
    
    return randomValue % max;
  }
}
```

To use this with a minimum value as well:

```
function getRandomIntInRange(min, max) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(min) || !Number.isInteger(max) || max <= min) {
    throw new Error("Both min and max should be integers with max > min.");
  }

  const range = max - min;
  const randomInt = getRandomInt(range);
  return randomInt + min;
}
```

Beware that this is **untested code**. I'm pretty sure it works, but **please test it before actual deployment**.

Comment: Warning `crypto` is only available when running a secure context. Also one would use `crypto` not because of any bias in `Math.random` (it is a rather good PRNG on the major browsers), but because random can be determined if one has knowledge of a set/sequence of results, which makes it insecure (not bias).

Comment: @Blindman67 **Any** secure code should be run in a secure context, i.e. over TLS :) I've changed the wording w.r.t. the CSPRNG, I didn't want to indicate that this has anything to do with using floating point, just that it is something that I would change as well.

Comment: Javascript uses double-precision floating-point values, with a precision of roughly 15 to 17 digits. That's a lot. I don't think this "bias" will be a problem in normal applications, but it is good to be aware of it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yeah, you're right. Of course there are other reasons to use a cryptographic random instead of a normal random, e.g. you cannot calculate the state and find other random values before or after the random produced. You'll quickly find that `getRandomValues` will only return integer based arrays, so then you'd have to produce a double precision float from that , and in that case you might as well use rejection sampling.